# What happens when GCM topics limit exceeded?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

From [documentations](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging),
we can get TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS error, when try to send push message to topic.

Are messages sent or topics stop working?

From this point we need to send messages using tokens?

Should we use tokens instead of topics from the beginning?

Is this error comes only to server?

If yes, why it's recommended to unsubscribe device from topic?

Is it possible to catch this error at the client?